# Call function with QDBusInterface in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a DBus connection, which should serve some 3D coordinates `(QVector3D)` from the server side. I see the session-bus object `/org/track/control` is already in D-Feet application and the function `getCoordinates()` there, gives me correct values. My question is, How should I call that function in pyqt? If I call it like : `dBusInterface.call('getCoordinates')` than I get following error:

```
QDBusMarshaller: type `PyQt_PyObject' (1025) is not registered with D-BUS. Use qDBusRegisterMetaType to register it

Call failed: No such method 'getCoordinates' in any interface at object path '/org/track/control' (signature 's')
```

I could not find any tutorial or example for `qDBusRegisterMetaType` in pyqt4 or 5

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtDBus import *

def connect_dbus(self):
    self.dBusConnection= QDBusConnection.connectToBus('tcp:host=localhost,port=55556', 'myBus')
    if not self.dBusConnection.isConnected():
        print("Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n"
                         "To start it, run:\n"
                         "\teval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`\n");
    else:
        print('Connected to the DBus session bus')


    serviceObject = 'org.track.control'
    serviceName = '/org/track/control'
    dBusInterface = QDBusInterface(serviceObject, serviceName, '', self.dBusConnection)

    if dBusInterface.isValid():
        print('Registered to the DBus service: '+ serviceObject)
    else:
        print('Failed to register DBus service object: '+ serviceObject)

    msg = dBusInterface.call('getCoordinates')
    reply = QDBusReply(msg)

    if reply.isValid():
        sys.stdout.write("Reply was: %s\n" % reply.value())
        sys.exit()

    print("Call failed: %s\n" % reply.error().message())
    print("%s\n" % QDBusConnection.sessionBus().lastError().message())
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. I should call the function with an integer. Cause I had 3 sources, which produce coordinates in server, then the function call in client:

```
for i in range(3):
  # Gives coords from all sources
  msg = dBusInterface.call('getCoordinates', i) 
  reply = QDBusReply(msg)
  ...
```